# Ideal Settlement Location for Time Travelers

Tags: geography, time-travel, colonization, prehistoric-times

If a group of time travelers dedicated to travel back 10 million years and settle a humanless earth, where might they decide to found this first colony?

Assume that these temporal colonists are well funded and supplied, but can't receive additional support due to the erasure of the original timeline.

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information than this.  How many people are there?  What tools and supplies are they taking with them?  Why are they traveling back in time in order to colonize?  Without that information, we're only guessing.

Comment: Do they need specific resources near their new settlement (e.g. will they still want to use certain machinery, or be able to repair their modern devices)?

Answer (score 4):

They would best survive in a place that offered fresh water and abundant food, but also offer protection from larger predators. The inner rim of an extinct volcano that had a lake. Fish could provide protein while the steep walls would prevent large predators from gaining access and keep the winds down. No floods or tornadoes or hurricanes.  Driving prey over the steep walls could provide additional food perhaps. Maybe even thermal vents for a constant source of heat even in snowstorms. Obsidian for cutting utensils and fertile soil for agriculture. An island in the lake would offer absolute protection like Crater Lake Oregon.

Comment: "We're here. Where's the crater?" "We should be right in the center. Hey, what's that bright ball of light in the sky? It looks like it's getting closer.” 

Comment: Yep.  Kauai was going to be my answer.  And back then there would be no mosquitoes, so you could sleep outside in the buff.

Answer (score 4):

### Throw them to the lions (please)

Our proposal would be to pop up these land animals inside a cave occupied by  tigers and bears and let them be eaten ASAP.

**There we go again**

Lesson zero humans, you don't *settle*. Time travel is supposed to be *temporary* activity. You go in.. and you go out again. Keep a low profile and clear your mess behind you.

Q: *"Assume that these temporal colonists are well funded and supplied, but can't receive additional support due to the erasure of the original timeline."*

Sure, bet they are well-funded..

Cowboys. Let me guess, their time line got erased and now they are supposed to repair things, reconstructing some lousy scheme of ape evolution ? What about other people's time lines ? What about the octopus, what about *our* timeline, dear apes ?

[image]

We've sent them signals, warned them for the dangers of uncertified TT for years, but their government never listened to us. Apes never change. And they don't think.

Comment: It's about time that Octopi remove the technology needed for time travel from those upstart apes!

Comment: We can't. But their timeline will collapse again when they stay. There's a lot of butterflies out there.

Comment: Where humans have always settled, in wide valleys near a large river.

Comment: Ahh large river.. ok... now suppose they catch a fish and kill it.. do you have any idea what that could do with their ancestors survival ? As expected, there's a lot of time travel nitwits on this ape forum..

Answer (score 1):

- **South America**.  At this time, the Great American Interchange had not yet occurred.  That means that South America is well stocked with weird, wonderful marsupial species that on average did poorly against placental mammals.  Its lack of great apes should limit the exposure to disease somewhat, though as we all know even bats can give us something we won't like.  Your colonists are more likely to be successful with their livestock where desired, provided they *carefully and thoughtfully* consider how to avoid environmental disaster.
- **Major cities** are proven sites for colonization.  Of course, the technological circumstances are different, and the landscape has [significant variations](http://latinalista.com/new-headline/scientists-make-starting-discovery-of-when-panama-linked-north-and-south-america) from the modern topology.  In general, where a usable river meets the sea is a good spot - even in the modern world we do most shipping with ships, and like any colonists your group has no road system to use.  Floodplains and even the courses of rivers may vary, so the correspondence of your ancient city to the now-nonexistent modern city will be very approximate.
- **Scout for mineral resources**.  This is very dependent on the scenario, but a [very basic map](https://geography.name/latin-america-landforms-and-resources/) might give ideas about areas with a nice collection of useful resources like coal, iron, aluminum, oil, gas ... all the stuff you need to fire up your civilization, destroy the planet and get ready to reboot at 20 MYA as quick as you can.  Time's a-wasting!

To take a random pick, I'm going to say **Montevideo**.  It is somewhat isolated behind the Rio de la Plata and Uruguay River, allowing you to more plausibly confine a placental mammal agriculture, and is good farming territory.  The city is prosperous in modern times, and close to the mineral resources of Argentina and the Brazilian highlands, and receives waters from the Paraguay River that at least in modern times is navigable all the way to Bolivia's rich mineral resources.  Being close to the Straits of Magellan, it is somewhat well placed for global commerce - though we should recall the Panama Canal is working quite well at 10 MYA!  Your colonists *may* prefer its temperate climate, though that is my culturally influenced bias.